# Is there an error in Susskinds' derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, discrete

[image: screenshot of text]

First, I believe there is a trivial error. The second equation should have another $\Delta  t$ multiplying everything on the right. It is divided out later when the equation I set equal to 0.

1. Given that $L$ is a function of $ x_7, x_8, x_9$ how can he justify evaluating it at single points?
2. Also, why are points 8 and 9 used rather than 7 and 8?

For context, this is the last equation on page 112 and the first equation on page 113 of Susskind's The Theoretical Minimum.

Comment: Related question about Susskinds' video: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22185/2451 . Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68184/2451

Comment: I have edited this old question so that a reader doesn’t have to visit an external site to understand it. However, [screenshots of text are still generally a bad idea](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I agree it looks like the second equation is missing an overall factor of $\Delta t$ on the right.

The *action* is a function of all the $x$s for the whole trajectory, but the *Lagrangian* is not.  It is only a function of a position and a velocity.  So it makes perfect sense to evaluate it using the position and velocity for a single time.

Points 8 and 9 are used because (I guess) the action is defined as  a sum of terms involving $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$, so the terms that involve $x_8$ are the 8th and 9th terms.  If he had defined the action using $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ then he would have had to take the 7th and 8th terms instead.  It's just a choice of convention.

Comment: I don't understand how he can have an equation with two variables and then treat it as though it is composed of one in the next step. Also,  the $x_7$ and $x_8$ terms are included in the series also. See the second line of the first equation.

Comment: @MadScientist No, the $n$th term depends on $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$.  So the $n = 8$ term depends on $x_8$ and $x_7$, while the $n = 9$ term depends on $x_9$ and $x_8$.  Those are the only terms that depend on $x_8$.  So to get the total dependence on $x_8$ he only needs to evaluate things at $n = 8$ and $n = 9$.

Comment: I'm not seeing why he can't choose points 7 and 8.

Comment: @MadScientist The $n = 7$ term only depends on $x_7$ and $x_6$, so it's irrelevant to $x_8$.  And if you leave out the $n = 9$ term you don't capture *all* the dependence of the action on $x_8$.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. Everything makes sense. I was confused.

Answer (score -2):

I still think it might be wrong. 
the 8th term is dependant on x8 and x9 and the 7th term is dependant on x7 and x8.
Therefore L should be evaluated at n=8 and n= 7.